# How the Change Aurelia Source Directory From Src to App

Tags: aurelia

Hopefully this is the simplest question in the world but I can't find it anywhere through google. The default structure from Aurelia came like this-

```
node_modules/
jspm_packages/
src/
  app.html
  app.ts
config.js
index.html
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

I don't like this because I don't want my buildable source files to live with dev files like `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, and all of `node_modules`. Additionally, I'm using gulp so it becomes even more cluttered. Here is how I'd like to structure my app-

```
gulp-tasks/
node_modules/
src/
  app/
    components/
    app.html
    app.ts
  bower_components/
  jspm_packages/
  config.js
  index.html
gulpfile.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

But it's like Aurelia is hard coded to look for `src/`. I've updated my config to look for `app/app.html` but I think it's looking for `src/app/app.html`. How can I update Aurelia to use the project structure I want?

Comment: have you tried to set the root component in the  (usually)  `main.js` file? Check out http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.8/doc/article/app-configuration-and-startup see "Rendering the Root Component"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `build/paths.js`:

```
var appRoot = 'src/app';
var outputRoot = 'src/dist/';
//... leave unmodified
```

Create a `main.js` file, inside src/app/:

```
//ES6/7
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('app/app'));
}

//TypeScript
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia): void {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot('app/app'));
}
```

In the `index.html` set the `main.js` in the `aurelia-app` attribute. Like this:

```
<body aurelia-app="app/main">
```

Close gulp watch task (if running) and run it again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So now it looks like it's looking for `main.js` automagically but I'm using `main.ts`. Going to play around with it for a bit but either way you answered my question so thank you.

Comment: Now that I think of it this may be a deeper issue. Do I need to compile my ts or will aurelia do that for me?

Comment: To be honest with you, I never used Aurelia with TypeScript, but I believe the gulp task will compile for you every time you change the file